# Ansible output to a file

Tags: linux, automation, ansible

I would like to get mac and nics of every ansbile host to a specific txt file using the following syntax:

```
nic:XXXXX,MAC:XXXXXX
nic:XXXXX,MAC:XXXXXX
```

what is the right way to so?

At this point I was able only to have this as an output from a playbook I've created:

```
  - debug:
      msg: "nic:{{ (lookup('vars', concat)).device }},mac:{{ (lookup('vars', concat)).macaddress }}"
    vars:
      concat: "ansible_{{ item }}"
    loop: "{{ ansible_interfaces | difference(['lo']) }}"
```

The only thing left to do is output the content to a text file using the mentioned syntax.
How can I do so?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is written on spot, untested: you may have to add some tests and default values for undefined vars. I also guessed from you question that you will need the hostname in your file at some point. If I was wrong, juste remove it. In a nutshell:

`templates/nic_mac.txt.j2`

```
{% for h in group['all'] %}
{% for i in (hostvars[h].ansible_interfaces | difference(['lo']) %}
host:{{ hostvars[h].inventory_hostname }},nic:{{ hostvars[h]['ansible_'+i].device }},MAC:{{ hostvars[h]['ansible_'+i].macaddress }}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

`playbook.yml`

```yaml
---
- name: Make sure we have facts for all hosts
  hosts: all
  # This play will only trigger facts gathering, nothing else

- name: Write nic and mac info to a file on controller
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: Write the file from template
      template:
        src: nic_mac.txt.j2
        dest: /tmp/nic_mac.txt
```